# Populate Firebase Database With Python

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there a way to populate my firebase database from within python code? Or is there not, because python isn't used to write web/iphone/or android apps?

My code is currently this:

```
  page = requests.get('http://www.eatlowcarbon.org/food-scores')
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

  foodDict = {}
  aTag = soup.findAll('a', class_="food")

  for tag in aTag:
          name = tag.find("div", {'class':"name"}).text

          score = tag.find("div", {'class':"score"}).text
          foodDict[name] = score
```

And instead of putting the information in a dictionary, I'd like to put it in my firebase database.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase recently releases its admin SDK for python.

You should definitely use it since it's officially supported. Here's the link to the list of available sdk.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

Answer (score 0):

It's not firebase, and not necessarily a solution, but amazon's relational database is an option perhaps: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-rds.html